# Defining a list using set theory?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

EDIT: Changed set

If I have the following set of numbers: $\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16,...\}$ where the universe of discourse is natural numbers $\{0, 1, 2, ...\}$

How can I define this? I note that definitions are usually in the form of {x | P(X)}, but in this case, is it valid to write $\{2^x | x \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes $\{2^x\, |\, x \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is fine. It's a shorthand for $\{y\in\mathbb{N} \,|\, \exists x\in \mathbb{N}, 2^x = y\}$.

If you actually meant $\{1,2,4,8,16\}$ and no more elements, then just write that. Alternatively, use $\{y\in\mathbb{N} \,|\, \exists x\in \mathbb{N}, 2^x = y, x < 5\}$

Comment: Thanks, I missed the lack of $\ldots$, though I think OP did actually mean all of them, given that he wrote $\{2^x\,|\,x\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken.  I meant $\{1,2,4,8,16,...\}$ and have corrected my question